# Command Executs when Enter Key is Pressed Twice

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, prism

I have a combobox. I have some input bindings on it as follows:

```
<ComboBox .........>

    <ComboBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteUnwantedOrderItemTransactionCommand, 
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type coreUI:UserControlViewBase}}}"
                    Gesture="Return" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteUnwantedOrderItemTransactionCommand, 
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type coreUI:UserControlViewBase}}}"
                    Gesture="Tab" />
    </ComboBox.InputBindings>

</ComboBox>
```

In ViewModel I have RelayCommands as Follows:

```
public RelayCommand DeleteUnwantedOrderItemTransactionCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand AddNewOrderItemTransactionCommand { get; set; }

public OrderViewModel(IEventAggregator _eventAggregator)
{
    eventAggregator = _eventAggregator;

    DeleteUnwantedOrderItemTransactionCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteUnwantedOrderItemTransaction);
    AddNewOrderItemTransactionCommand = new RelayCommand(AddNewOrderItemTransaction);
}

protected void DeleteUnwantedOrderItemTransaction(object obj)
{
    if (!(SelectedOrderItemTransaction.ItemId > 0))
    {
        NewOrder.OrderItemTransactions.Remove(SelectedOrderItemTransaction);
    }

    if (NewOrder.OrderItemTransactions.Count == 0)
    {
        NewOrder.OrderItemTransactions.Add(new OrderItemTransaction());
    }

    eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeFocusToNextUIElementEvent>().Publish(true);
}

protected void AddNewOrderItemTransaction(object obj)
{
    if (SelectedOrderItemTransaction == NewOrder.OrderItemTransactions.Last())
        NewOrder.OrderItemTransactions.Add(new OrderItemTransaction());

    eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeFocusToNextUIElementEvent>().Publish(true);
}
```

Then in CodeBehind:

```
public OrderView(OrderViewModel _viewModel, IEventAggregator _eventAggregator)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeFocusToNextUIElementEvent>().Subscribe(MoveToNextUIElement);
}

void MoveToNextUIElement(bool obj)
{
    // Gets the element with keyboard focus.
    UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

    if (elementWithFocus != null)
    {
        elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I have specified in the InputBindings that when user Presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I want to execute a RelayCommand and on completion of execution that Command, I want to Move Focus to the next element.

In this case:

When I Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> everything works fine. The Command is executed and focus moves to next Element.

But when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> 1<sup>st</sup> time, The Item is selected in the ComboBox. Command Does not Fire and So, Focus does not move to the next element. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> 2<sup>nd</sup> the Command executes and focus moves to the next Control as expected.

**But I don't want this behavior. I want to Execute Command and Move Focus to the next element when 1<sup>st</sup> time <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.**

Comment: The problem is the ComboBox is processing the keyboard event. You probably need to add `PreviewKeyDown` (or `PreviewKeyUp`) event, check for "Enter" key, and set it as handled. Never tested it myself though.

Comment: @Jai I tried it just now. When using PreviewKeyDown and capturing Enter Key and set e.Handled = true, My Command stops executing. When using PreviewKeyUp I get the same behavior as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked at ComboBox source codes.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Let ComboBox's original method handle it
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    // Manually check if the ComboBox handled an "Enter" key
    // If yes, set e.Handled back to false so that Command binding can consume the same event
    Key key = e.Key;
    if (key == Key.Enter)
        e.Handled = false;
}
```

Just saying - I didn't test this either! But I think it should work. If not try doing it for `OnKeyDown()` as well. Apparently ComboBox has both methods, and both calls a private method `KeyDownHandler(KeyEventArgs e)`, which we cannot override.

Comment: Thank you Jai. That works perfectly. No need to override OnKeyDown().